# Flutter - Dart - Make image full screen size

Tags: flutter, dart

I want my image to fit the screen, for now I have :

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            child: Image.file(File(_path)),
          )
        ),
```

Which doesn't work, the image doesn't fit full screen.

I read about `DecorationImage` and after some tests, it makes possible to have the image to fill the full screen. But I didn't find any informatins about how to use it with `Image.file`. Is it possible ?

Comment: remove `Stack` and `Center` and `FittedBox` - `Image` widget can show your image in full screen without them

Comment: Ok I will give a try but I need to use Stack then since I have other Widgets (AppBar, Text...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did to put a Background in my app:

```
Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(_path),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      ... Other children
    ]
)
```

Comment: Yeah thanks ... but as I wrote in my question, how to deal with `Image.file()` ?

Comment: Exactly, If you've already got your image and know the path to it, replace the path in `AssetImage` with the path :D

Comment: Change your example with `AssetImage(_path)` please then I can accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

remove the safeArea and wrap the Image widget with a container.
Make a container of the same height and width as of screen size using mediaQuery.
I don't see use for Center() here.

```
 Container(
  height:MediaQuery.of<context>.size.height,
  width:MediaQuery.of<context>.size.width,
  child: Stack(
   children: <Widget>[
    Center(
      child: FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        child: Image.file(File(_path)),
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace Center widget with Container and mark its height, width as infinity

```
body: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                width: double.infinity,
              child: FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                child: Image.file(File(_path)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        ));
```